# how to get sub string with with in c# with specific paterns

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have following string patern

```
string str = "MCHH-1-00001";
```

I need to check 00001 value every time before page load and increment it by '1' 
please tell me how i can do this.

Comment: what have you attempted/

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: The text before the pattern will be same in every condition ?

Comment: yes first part would be static for this specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

```
string[] value= str.Split('-');
```

and get value like

```
string numericValue=value[2];
```

Comment: patel that going to help. great thaks

Answer (score 2):

If the first part is static:

```
string identifier = "MCHH-1-";
int num = int.Parse(str.Substring(identifier.Length));
str = identifier + (++num).ToString("D5");
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/Sc2lRr)